# how website find them the request come from a browser or from any other

Tags: request, httprequest

how website checked that a request come from a browser or from a programs.

Comment: This question is un-decipherable.  Consider adding an example.

Comment: @ Mex i want to check out the request come from a browser or a programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in javascript you may use navigator.userAgent. note that this may vary from browser to browser. a good example how to use it can be found at 
[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html).

However be aware that you can edit the userAgentString at any time using the appropriate browser, script or code. so no absolute guarantee on the result - but at least a starting point.

cheers,
markus

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer to use server side code, and presuming you are using .net, the Request.Browser property will provide details of the agent making the request.